# Python (with selenium) how to modify and activate elements to update webpage before scraping data

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data from https://marvelsnapzone.com/decks/ but I would like to modify the table of decks before scraping them.  For example:
Adding card names:
I am trying to add new `div id="tagsblock"` with certain names like `class="tag card" "Angela "`

Executing the "Search":
I would then like to execute the `id="searchdecks"` command to update the table of decks

Sorting by ascending "Likes":
Lastly I want to edit the `span data-sorttype="likes" class` to say `span data-sorttype="likes" class ="asc"`

Below is my current python script which doesn't seem to sort the "Likes" before scraping the deck info.  It also currently does not add cards or execute the "Search".

```
import re
import requests
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def scrap():
    url = 'https://marvelsnapzone.com/decks'

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.headless = True
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    browser.get(url)
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    
    # I would like to add cards and execute the "Search" option here

    selects = soup.findAll('span', {'data-sorttype': 'likes'})
    for select in selects:
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'asc')", select) 
        # this does not seem to sort the table, this is based on the data scraped later
    
    links = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'card cardtooltip maindeckcard tooltiploaded'})
    
    # ... more web-scraping code ...
    # I am able to scrape the information after this, but I am struggling to modify the table 
    # before scraping the information.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    characters = scrap()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually sites are dynamic and thus load new data via a script when you click on a button. This means that in these cases if you set an attribute with selenium the site will not change.

That said, your code has some errors which I think are caused by the fact that you think selenium and beautifulsoup talk to each other (i.e. interact).

1. By doing this

   ```
   soup = BeautifulSoup(...)
   browser.execute_script(...)
   links = soup.findAll(...)
   ```

   you are trying to "update" `soup` by executing a script, but it doesn't work like that, in fact `soup` is an immutable object. So when you run `soup.findAll(...)` you are using an "old" `soup` which doesn't contain the modifications following from `browser.execute_script(...)`.
2. By doing this

   ```
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'asc')", select)
   ```

   you are trying to use selenium to set an attribute of an object found with beautifulsoup. You cannot do this. The correct way is to find the element with selenium

   ```
   select = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-sorttype=likes]')
   browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'asc')", select)
   ```

   Anyway this doesn't work because as I said in the beginning, if you set an attribute with selenium the site will not change.
3. In this code block

   ```
   selects = soup.findAll('span', {'data-sorttype': 'likes'})
   for select in selects:
       # do something with select
   ```

   why doing a loop if you just want to set one attribute? Use `soup.find` (returns a webelement) instead of `soup.findAll` (returns a list, in this case a list with only one element)

   ```
   select = soup.find('span', {'data-sorttype': 'likes'})
   # do something with select
   ```

So the correct sequence of commands to sort the table and scrape it with beautifulsoup is the following

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://marvelsnapzone.com/decks'
browser.get(url)

# cookies popup is contained inside an iframe node, we must switch to it if we want to scrape elements inside it
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 50)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "gdpr-consent-notice")))

# close cookies popup
cookies = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'save')))
cookies.click()

number_of_rows = len(browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.related-decks-table tr'))

# like button
select = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-sorttype=likes]')
# scroll to like button, otherwise if not visible raises error "Element is not clickable"
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', select)
time.sleep(1)
select.click()

# wait to be sure that all elements in the sorted table are visible
table_rows = []
while len(table_rows) < number_of_rows:
    table_rows = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.related-decks-table tr')

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

links = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'card cardtooltip maindeckcard tooltiploaded'})
```

Notice that beautifulsoup is not mandatory to scrape the page, you can use selenium too.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, this makes sense.  However, when I run the script I get an error message saying that "Element is not clickable at point (317, 915)". Should I try running with a different browser?

Comment: @TomDekkard That is caused by the fact that the "likes" button is not directly visible, it may be hidden behind the cookies popup or it is located down in the page so a scroll is needed. I added code to prevent both cases. Test it and let me know